# JavaScript filter and map array data attribute with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

I have 2 drop-downs with data value string attribute each one, I wanna filter the result based on selection matching with listed div with data array value attribute,I am looking just the final step (filtering by selected  over the div with data array attribute and display only matching values) Here is the code:

```js
const $component = $('.inline-dropdown');
const $contentResults = $('.render-std');
$('.no-result').hide();

if ($component.length !== 0) {
  $component.find('.dropdown-list').on('dropdown-change', () => {

    const regionData = $('.regions').find('li.selected').attr('data-value');
    const brandData = $('.brands').find('li.selected').attr('data-value');

    const filterSelect = (val, index) => {
      const regionList = [regionData]; // select data-value regions
      const brandList = [brandData]; // select data-value brands

      return val == regionList || val == brandList;
    };

    // Not filter - Isuue here
    const listedItems = $contentResults.map((index, element) => {
      return element.dataset.values;
      //console.log(element.dataset.values);
    }).get();
    const filtered = listedItems.filter(filterSelect); // filter values by regions and brands
    // ./end

    renderContent(filtered);

  });
}

//render matches results from regions and brands select dropdown
const renderContent = (filtered) => {
  // show or hide result based select region and brands 
  if (!filtered.length) {
    console.log('No Result Matched');
    $contentResults.hide();
    $('.no-result').show();
  } else {
    console.log('Result Matched: ' + filtered);
    $contentResults.show();
    $('.no-result').hide();
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Select dropdown -->
<div class="inline-dropdown">
  <div class="resources regions">
    <div class="dropdown-list long">
      <a class="dropdown-list-box" class="selected">Select Region</a>
      <div class="dropdown-list-options-box-inner">
        <ul class="dropdown-list-options">
          <li data-value="latam"><a href="#">Latam</a></li>
          <li data-value="asia"><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
          <li data-value="usa"><a href="#">Usa</a></li>
          <li data-value="Canada"><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="resources brands">
    <div class="dropdown-list long">
      <a class="dropdown-list-box" class="selected">Select Brand</a>
      <div class="dropdown-list-options-box-inner">
        <ul class="dropdown-list-options">
          <li data-value="music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li data-value="sports"><a href="#">Spots</a></li>
          <li data-value="food"><a href="#">Food</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Results  -->
<div class="render-std" data-values="['latam','asia']">
  <div class="content-rb">
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./end -->

<!--  -->
<div class="render-std" data-values="['usa','sports','canada']">
  <div class="content-rb">
    <p>content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./end -->

<!--  -->
<div class="render-std" data-values="['usa','sports','food']">
  <div class="content-rb">
    <p>content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./end -->

<div class="no-result">
  <p>No results found</p>
</div>
```

Comment: based on the code you give,we can't trigger the dropdown-change event.So , we can't reproduce the problem you have met;

Comment: Got an error based on your fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined"    code:    const listedItems = $contentResults.toArray().map((index, element) => {
            //return element.dataset.values;
            console.log(element.dataset.values);
        });

Comment: Dropdown needs extra js to trigger css class selected item in dropdown.

Comment: add  console.log(val,regionList,brandList); before return val == regionList || val == brandList; you will find why,better show me the console.log(val,regionList,brandList)

Comment: and maybe the val is string not array,you can test it by typeof val

Comment: ** first dropdown (regions) selected:**
`0 > [“usa"] > [undefined]
1 > [“usa"] > [undefined]
2 > [“usa"] > [undefined]
3 > [“usa"] > [undefined]
Result Matched: [object Object]`


** second dropdown (brands) selected:**

`0 > [“usa"] > [“music”]
1 > [“usa"] > [“music”]
2 > [“usa"] > [“music”]
3 > [“usa"] > [“music”]
No Result Matched`

Comment: better updated the question with the console,i can see clear

Comment: another hint:  listedItems.filter ,you use the filter as jquery's filter or ES5's filter?if you use ES5's filter,i think you need to use like listedItems.toArray().filter

Comment: I already tried **listedItems.toArray().filter** without good luck.

Comment: Any idea? I am still stuck with it...